# How to display accent text in android?

Tags: android, textview

I'm displaying data from a database to `TextView` but the `TextView` with  accent text is geting `null`. How can I correct this error please

Comment: what error you getting paste

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Check the text value is null before setting it in TextView, also make sure you are not passing integer value.

Comment: I don't have an error but in the textview I got null, knowing that the text value is not null in the database. when I deleted the accent text from the database the textview is displaying correctly